# Multiple Html5 Videos not playing on ipad (but read on as i know the video is encoded properly)

Tags: html, video

I have followed many a tutorial to make sure that this is correct but this simply isn't working for me.
The code below works if I paste it into a fresh html page on the samer server (and this is cut and paste from the generated source):

```
<source src='http://turner.bionic-comms.co.uk/vids/rc/rc-iPhone.m4v'  type="video/mp4" /> 
<source src='http://turner.bionic-comms.co.uk/vids/rc/rc.mp4'  type="video/mp4" /> 
<source width='254' height='143' src='http://turner.bionic-comms.co.uk/vids/rc/rc.ogg'  type="video/ogg" /> 
<object width="254" height="143" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://turner.bionic-comms.co.uk/vids/video_player/video_player.swf"> 

<!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below --> 
<param name="movie" value="http://turner.bionic-comms.co.uk/vids/video_player/video_player.swf" /> 
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> 
<param name="flashvars" value="file=http://turner.bionic-comms.co.uk/vids/rc/rc.flv&image=http://turner.bionic-comms.co.uk/vids/rc/rc-poster.jpg" /> 

<!-- Fallback image. --> 
<img src="telematics_desktop.jpg" width="254" height="143" alt="telematics" title="No video playback capabilities." />
```

However, if I dynamically generate this code to have multiple videos on the page it breaks and doesn't play. I just get a black box.
The images are contained within a jquery booklet with pageturns.

Does anyone have any idea how I can sort this and get it playing? It works in safari and chrome.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with the encode , the problem is that iOS does not permit multiple instance of video player . this is written in the web site of apple . you can check it in this link
[Link in apple Site](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW10)

Currently, all devices running iOS are limited to playback of a single audio or video stream at any time. Playing more than one video—side by side, partly overlapping, or completely overlaid—is not currently supported on iOS devices. Playing multiple simultaneous audio streams is also not supported. You can change the audio or video source dynamically, however. See “Replacing a Media Source Sequentially” for details

Comment: Thanks man, had to put a lightbox alternative in place for them!

Comment: @Drew Have you found out a way to play multiple videos in html. please suggest me if you got it.

Comment: @Drew could you please post the answer here? I'm using a typical background video on my home's hero but I also need a video playing in a lightbox when I click a "view full video" button... Any help will be appreciated. Kind regards

Comment: Is this still the case? What if each of the videos are set to autoplay false?